# How can i Upload image files only using code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i'm trying to upload only image files using code igniter.I need to upload only png,jpg,jpeg files.but other type files also uploaded like .txt,.mp3 etc.my code is given below.please help me to solve this issue as immediately.Thanks to all in advance.

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './avatar/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|png|jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '1024mb';
    $config['max_width'] = '3000';
    $config['max_height'] = '3000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

        $ve['data'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else {
        $this->upload->data();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
// Alternately you can set preferences by calling the initialize function. Useful if you auto-load the //class:
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if($this->upload->do_upload())
{
  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
  $this->load->view('upload_success',$data);
}else
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('file_view', $error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send in the **user file/uploaded file** while trying to validate it within the if condition.

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
    $this->upload->data();
}
```